# If $H\leq G$ and $G-H$ is finite, then $G=H$ or $G$ is finite.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

> I'm trying to prove that if $H\leq G$ and $G-H$ is finite, then $G=H$ or $G$ is finite.

It is clear that if $|G-H|=0$ then $G=H$; otherwise, if $0<|G-H|=n<\infty$ then $|G:H|\leq|G-H|$.

The problem is that I can't find out how to use this fact to work out the proof.

Maybe this is not the right approach, so I would appreciate some hints, please.

Comment: Use that $G$ is a union of cosets of $H$, and that $H$ is itself such a coset. Draw a picture.

Comment: @Myself Oh, ok. It wasn't that hard. Thanks!

Comment: [Here is a discussion of what I have so far.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/47829263#47829263)

Comment: @Shaun The complement contains representatives for all but one coset as well as at least one full coset. So there are finitely many cosets and they are all finite.

Comment: Ah, I see! Thank you, @TobiasKildetoft. Would you mind posting that as an answer, please? It's just that it checks the question off the list of unanswered questions. If you don't want to, I'll copy & paste your comment as a community wiki answer (unless you have any objections) $\ddot\smile$

Comment: @Shaun Done....

Answer (score 2):

Let us assume that $H\neq G$ and show that then $G$ is finite.

Since the complement of $H$ in $G$ contains representatives of all but one of the cosets of $H$ in $G$ (missing only the coset $H$), there are finitely many cosets of $H$ in $G$.

But the complement also contains at least one full coset, so this coset is finite and hence all cosets are finite.

Since $G$ is the union of these finitely many finite cosets, it is itself finite.